# How do I add links to images in this javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need help please. How do I add links to images in the code below. This is a script that allows visitors to click a choice on a dropdown menu in a form, and every choice changes the image presented. I am trying to add a link to each image that will allow the visitors to hover their mouse over the image and it opens up a larger image.

I just need to know where to add the link. Everytime I add it in the var sel_imgs=[ , it disables the function of changing the images when the visitor selects an option in the dropdown menu.

```
function diva_imgBySel(objId,theValue) { //v0.1 divaHTML.com

    var sel_imgs=["images/md01.jpeg","images/md01.jpeg","images/md02.jpeg","images/md03.jpeg","images/md04.jpeg","images/md06.jpeg","images/md05.jpeg","images/pic07.jpeg","images/pic08.jpeg"];

    var d=document;
    theValue=sel_imgs[theValue];
    if (!theValue || !d.getElementById ) return;
    var obj = d.getElementById(objId);
    if (obj) obj.src=theValue;    
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
</script>
```

And here is the form code lower down on the page:

```
<img src="images/md01.jpeg" alt="" name="theImg" width="147" height="161" id="theImg" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;" align="LEFT" /><strong>Add a vase:</strong>
<input type="checkbox" name="anniv" id="anniv" value="6.95" onclick="priceUpdate('anniv');"/>
             &pound;6.95
            </td>
          <td width="71%" align="left" valign="top"> <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="left"></br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="productColors" id="productColors" style="width:270px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px" onchange="diva_imgBySel('theImg',this.selectedIndex)">
                <option value="MD1004">Select Flower Arrangement</option>
                <option value="MD1004">Bloom</option>
                <option value="MD1001">Majestic</option>
                <option value="MD1007">Mothers Day Premium</option>
                <option value="MD1002">Mum's the Word</option>
                <option value="NF1011">Joyful Orchids</option>
                <option value="NF1010">Lily and Rose Hand Tied</option>
                <option value="NF1013">Sunflower Sensation</option>
                <option value="SF002-free-vase">Tranquililty</option>
                </select></td>
```

Here is the node with the mouseover effect attached. it works fine, but repeats the same large image for each selection the user makes. I need to know how to duplicate this effect for each image not just "md01.jpeg".

```
<a href="#" rel="imgtip[1]"><img src="images/md01.jpeg" alt="" name="theImg" width="147" height="161" id="theImg" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;" align="LEFT" /><a/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ddimgtooltip.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="ddimgtooltip.js">

/***********************************************
* Image w/ description tooltip v2.0- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

</script>
```

Here is the code for image mouseover. It is a .js file

```
/* Image w/ description tooltip v2.0
* Created: April 23rd, 2010. This notice must stay intact for usage 
* Author: Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
*/


var ddimgtooltip={

    tiparray:function(){
        var tooltips=[]
        //define each tooltip below: tooltip[inc]=['path_to_image', 'optional desc', optional_CSS_object]
        //For desc parameter, backslash any special characters inside your text such as apotrophes ('). Example: "I\'m the king of the world"
        //For CSS object, follow the syntax: {property1:"cssvalue1", property2:"cssvalue2", etc}

        tooltips[0]=["images/pic01.jpg"]
        tooltips[1]=["images/pic02.jpg"]
        tooltips[2]=["images/pic03.jpg"]
        tooltips[3]=["images/pic04.jpeg"]
        tooltips[4]=["images/pic05.jpeg"]
        tooltips[5]=["images/pic06.jpeg"]

        return tooltips //do not remove/change this line
    }(),

    tooltipoffsets: [20, -30], //additional x and y offset from mouse cursor for tooltips

    //***** NO NEED TO EDIT BEYOND HERE

    tipprefix: 'imgtip', //tooltip ID prefixes

    createtip:function($, tipid, tipinfo){
        if ($('#'+tipid).length==0){ //if this tooltip doesn't exist yet
            return $('<div id="' + tipid + '" class="ddimgtooltip" />').html(
                '<div style="text-align:center"><img src="' + tipinfo[0] + '" /></div>'
                + ((tipinfo[1])? '<div style="text-align:left; margin-top:5px">'+tipinfo[1]+'</div>' : '')
                )
            .css(tipinfo[2] || {})
            .appendTo(document.body)
        }
        return null
    },

    positiontooltip:function($, $tooltip, e){
        var x=e.pageX+this.tooltipoffsets[0], y=e.pageY+this.tooltipoffsets[1]
        var tipw=$tooltip.outerWidth(), tiph=$tooltip.outerHeight(), 
        x=(x+tipw>$(document).scrollLeft()+$(window).width())? x-tipw-(ddimgtooltip.tooltipoffsets[0]*2) : x
        y=(y+tiph>$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height())? $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-tiph-10 : y
        $tooltip.css({left:x, top:y})
    },

    showbox:function($, $tooltip, e){
        $tooltip.show()
        this.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
    },

    hidebox:function($, $tooltip){
        $tooltip.hide()
    },


    init:function(targetselector){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var tiparray=ddimgtooltip.tiparray
            var $targets=$(targetselector)
            if ($targets.length==0)
                return
            var tipids=[]
            $targets.each(function(){
                var $target=$(this)
                $target.attr('rel').match(/\[(\d+)\]/) //match d of attribute rel="imgtip[d]"
                var tipsuffix=parseInt(RegExp.$1) //get d as integer
                var tipid=this._tipid=ddimgtooltip.tipprefix+tipsuffix //construct this tip's ID value and remember it
                var $tooltip=ddimgtooltip.createtip($, tipid, tiparray[tipsuffix])
                $target.mouseenter(function(e){
                    var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                    ddimgtooltip.showbox($, $tooltip, e)
                })
                $target.mouseleave(function(e){
                    var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                    ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip)
                })
                $target.mousemove(function(e){
                    var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                    ddimgtooltip.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
                })
                if ($tooltip){ //add mouseenter to this tooltip (only if event hasn't already been added)
                    $tooltip.mouseenter(function(){
                        ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $(this))
                    })
                }
            })

        }) //end dom ready
    }
}

//ddimgtooltip.init("targetElementSelector")
ddimgtooltip.init("*[rel^=imgtip]")
```

Comment: Try to ditch dreamweaver it makes your code impossibly complicated. Find a good IDE or text editor, many of them are free. it will make you a better developer. Try [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.5.html) if you are on windows

Comment: @Ibu Dreamweaver is a good IDE for several languages (php, coldfusion, javascript, etc) and is probably the best product around for CSS/HTML... you should probably clarify to: "Dreamweaver makes your code impossibly complicated **when used as a WYSIWYG editor**... and its pre-built code blocks can be a bit hard to parse. However, it does a great job at code highlighting, displaying html/css including `include()`ed files (shtml,php,etc), argument suggestion (js,php,etc), and syntax error warnings. The problems crop up when you rely on it to actually do the code-writing for you.

Answer (score 0):

This code sample doesn't actually refer to the markup you want to focus on.  WHat you've got here is the logic and form elements will change the src of the img tag with an id of 'theImg'.  What you need to look at is the element with the 'theImg' id and add a listener there to fire whatever large image effect that you want.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thats exactly what I was trying to say!! Sorry I am a newbie to this. How would i go about doing that? How do i add links within that 'theImg' id element. A link for each image. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: We'd probably need to see a bit more code in order to help out.  Specifically, we'd need to see the image node.  Look in the code for something along the lines of ' id="theImg" ' and add the complete node the code in the original question.

Comment: Oh ok. I found a line just above the form that I think has the image node. Thanks. Let me know if I need to paste more of the code.

Comment: Bingo!  :)  Ok, so the idea is that you want to trigger the "large image display" effect when the user hovers over the image node.  It can get pretty involved depending on how you want the larger image to display (new window, fill up the current window, in a lightbox, etc), but for where you're at, the easiest would be to add an onmouseover event listener.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmouseover for some good explanation and code examples.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified a bit more. I already have a code for the mouseover. The problem is when i attached it to the node, it works, but it shows the same large image for every selection the visitor makes. So when they select another choice in the dropdown list on the form, the image changes as expected, but the mouseover image stays the same. What I am trying to figure out is how to add a different large image mouseover link to each image. Hope this makes sense. I will edit the node code in my original post to show my mouseover effect.

Comment: Sounds like the mouseover is either hard-coded with an image src or it's not looking to get the current image src.  Look inside the mouseover function to see how it's generating the src for the larger image render.  My guess is you'd need to update it to grab the src from the #theImg node and inject it into the larger image src attribute.

Comment: Yes I looked into it, and I had to set every large image I want in the .js code. I understand what you are saying regarding updating it to grab the src from the #theImg node; but I honestly do not know how to do this. I have now attached the code of the mouseover function. Any help or link to a tutorial that can help me alter it for my requirements would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Brian.

Comment: Yeah that plugin looks like it assumes all of the thumbs will be on the page when it's invoked.  Since you're dynamically updating the thumb source, you'll need to either instantiate the tooltip every time the thumb source is changed or dive in and edit the section under where it says 'NO NEED TO EDIT BEYOND HERE'.  :)

Comment: THanks for pointing me in the right direction Brian. Still dont know exactly how to do it ie instantiating the tooltip or what exactly to edit in the code; but will play around and see if I'm lucky. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="MD1001"><a href="your_link"><img src="your_image_path"/></a>Your non-Link Text</option>
```

That's how I would lay it out. I'm not sure what exactly your asking for. But this will put an image in there. Just replace the "your_link" , "your_image_path" with your data.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before, but because the form itself calls the images from the function script I first showed on here, it disregards the image placed within the form.